# Is it possible to order a v-snackbar below the temporary v-navigation-drawer?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to place the v-navigation-drawer over a v-snackbar if the navigation drawer has the "temporary" prop set. Usually, the snackbar respects the navigation drawer when the app prop is set on the snackbar, but not when the drawer has the temporary prop.

I can understand how this could be an expected behavior at some times, but I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse the order for them in any way.

This can become an issue when viewing the app on mobile for example:
[image]

In the above example, the snackbar has fully covered the first option in the navigation drawer and renders it inaccessible until the snackbar times out or is dismissed.

**I've tried leveraging the elevation prop on the v-snackbar and the elevation class on v-navigation-drawer but that doesn't seem to help with the issue.**

Here's a self-contained codepen showing the issue:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ceiling-Gecko/pen/wvoQaXE)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      snackbar: false
    };
  },
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer temporary app v-model="drawer">
      Hello I'm the Drawer
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar app fixed>
      <v-btn @click="drawer = !drawer; snackbar = true">
        Trigger
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-snackbar app top left v-model="snackbar">
      I'm Blocking the Drawer
      <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
          <v-btn dark icon v-bind="attrs"
                 @click="snackbar = false">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-snackbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: If the snack bar comes beneath the drawer, then how will the users read the message that's written on the snack bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky workaround is to set the `z-index` of the drawer to be higher than the snackbar's (`v-snackbar` has `z-index: 1000`).

```html
<v-navigation-drawer temporary app :style="{ 'z-index': 2000 }">
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LYbXLrm?editors=1010)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      snackbar: false
    };
  },
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer temporary app v-model="drawer" :style="{ 'z-index': 2000 }">
      Hello I'm the Drawer
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar app fixed>
      <v-btn @click="drawer = !drawer; snackbar = true">
        Trigger
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-snackbar app top left v-model="snackbar">
      I'm Not Blocking the Drawer
      <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
          <v-btn dark icon v-bind="attrs"
                 @click="snackbar = false">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-snackbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```